# How to extract multiple values from journalctl output

Tags: logging, sed, ethereum

I am trying to debug an ethereum beacon node which outputs logs with variable column data:

```
-- Logs begin at Sat 2021-01-30 19:05:03 CET, end at Wed 2021-02-24 11:19:14 CET. --
Feb 23 11:19:23 server beacon-chain[793]: time="2021-02-23 11:19:23" level=info msg="Synced new block" block=0x8f117f30... chainServiceProcessedTime=97.852794ms epoch=18884 finalizedEpoch=18882 finalizedRoot=0x9c26b9db... prefix=blockchain sinceSlotStartTime=504.745454ms slot=604295 slotInEpoch=7
Feb 23 11:19:23 server beacon-chain[793]: time="2021-02-23 11:19:23" level=info msg="Finished applying state transition" attestations=85 attesterSlashings=0 deposits=0 prefix=blockchain proposerSlashings=0 voluntaryExits=0
Feb 23 11:19:36 server beacon-chain[793]: time="2021-02-23 11:19:36" level=info msg="Synced new block" block=0xdf506bde... chainServiceProcessedTime=63.515885ms epoch=18884 finalizedEpoch=18882 finalizedRoot=0x9c26b9db... prefix=blockchain sinceSlotStartTime=1.492164357s slot=604296 slotInEpoch=8
Feb 23 11:19:36 server beacon-chain[793]: time="2021-02-23 11:19:36" level=info msg="Finished applying state transition" attestations=25 attesterSlashings=0 deposits=0 prefix=blockchain proposerSlashings=0 voluntaryExits=0
Feb 23 11:19:47 server beacon-chain[793]: time="2021-02-23 11:19:47" level=info msg="Synced new block" block=0x1785e975... chainServiceProcessedTime=81.050651ms epoch=18884 finalizedEpoch=18882 finalizedRoot=0x9c26b9db... prefix=blockchain sinceSlotStartTime=413.217351ms slot=604297 slotInEpoch=9
Feb 23 11:19:47 server beacon-chain[793]: time="2021-02-23 11:19:47" level=info msg="Finished applying state transition" attestations=61 attesterSlashings=0 deposits=0 prefix=blockchain proposerSlashings=0 voluntaryExits=0
...
```

I'm trying extract the values of `epoch`, `slot` and `sinceSlotStartTime`:

`journalctl -u servicename | sed -E -n 's/epoch=(\d*)|slot=(\d*)|sinceSlotStartTime=(\S*)ms/\1,\2,\3/p'`

However, this is just printing everything, any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: `sed` ERE doesn't support `\d`, `\S` etc use their POSIX equivalent like `[[:digit:]]` and `[^[:blank:]]`

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'm trying something simple like `sed -E -n 's/epoch=([[:digit:]]*)/\1/p'` and still finding it prints the entire line

Answer (score 2):

To parse a log file it is much easier to do this in `awk`:

```sh
awk '{s=""; for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if ($i ~ /^(epoch|slot|sinceSlotStartTime)=/) {sub(/[^=]+=/, "", $i); s = s (s == "" ? "" : ",") $i+0} if (s) print s}' file

18884,504.745,604295
18884,1.49216,604296
18884,413.217,604297
```

PS: `sed` ERE doesn't support Perl regex properties like `\d`, `\S` etc We have to use their POSIX equivalent like `[[:digit:]]` and `[^[:blank:]]` however `sed` would still be a bit more challenging for this than `awk`.

Expanded `awk` command:

```sh
awk '{
   s = ""
   for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
      if ($i ~ /^(epoch|slot|sinceSlotStartTime)=/) {
         sub(/[^=]+=/, "", $i)
         s = s (s == "" ? "" : ",") $i+0
      }
   if (s)
      print s
}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Any time you have tag-value pairs in your input I find it best to first populate an array of that mapping (`tag2val` below) and then you can print or do any other operations on whatever values you want just be referring to them by their tags (names):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS = ","
    numTags = split("epoch slot sinceSlotStartTime",tags)
    for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
        tag = tags[tagNr]
        printf "%s%s", tag, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
/Synced new block/ {
    delete tag2val
    while ( match($0,/[^[:space:]]+=([^[:space:]]+|"[^"]+")/) ) {
        tag = val = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        sub(/=.*/,"",tag)
        sub(/[^=]*=/,"",val)
        tag2val[tag] = val
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }

    for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
        tag = tags[tagNr]
        val = tag2val[tag]
        printf "%s%s", val, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
epoch,slot,sinceSlotStartTime
18884,604295,504.745454ms
18884,604296,1.492164357s
18884,604297,413.217351ms
```

If you want to print other fields or print in a different order than all you have to do is update the string `"epoch slot sinceSlotStartTime"` in the call to `split()`.

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
 journalctl -u servicename | sed -En 's/(^.*)(epoch=)([[:digit:]]+)(.*)(sinceSlotStartTime=)([[:digit:]]+)(.*)(slot=)([[:digit:]]+)(.*$)/\3,\6,\9/p'
```

Enable regular expression interpretation with -E or -r and then split the line into sections designated with parenthesis. Substitute the line for the third, sixth  and ninth sections, separated by commas.